# Exception addWorkLog JIRA JAVA REST CLIENT

Tags: java, jira

I have the a problem ith Jira Rest Client API.
I got a Exception using addWorkLog:

```
com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.RestClientException: 
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.jersey.AbstractJerseyRestClient.invoke(AbstractJerseyRestClient.java:68)
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.jersey.AbstractJerseyRestClient.post(AbstractJerseyRestClient.java:135)
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.jersey.JerseyIssueRestClient.addWorklog(JerseyIssueRestClient.java:451)
    at ConexionJira.main(ConexionJira.java:273)
Caused by: com.sun.jersey.api.client.UniformInterfaceException: Client response status: 404
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.voidHandle(WebResource.java:707)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.post(WebResource.java:236)
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.jersey.AbstractJerseyRestClient$6.call(AbstractJerseyRestClient.java:141)
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.jersey.AbstractJerseyRestClient$6.call(AbstractJerseyRestClient.java:135)
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.jersey.AbstractJerseyRestClient.invoke(AbstractJerseyRestClient.java:54)
```

My code is the next:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws URISyntaxException{
JerseyJiraRestClientFactory factory = new JerseyJiraRestClientFactory();
URI jiraServerUri = new URI("http://web.web.com/jira");
JiraRestClient restClient = factory.createWithBasicHttpAuthentication(jiraServerUri, "asd", "asd");
IssueRestClient irc = restClient.getIssueClient();
NullProgressMonitor pm = new NullProgressMonitor();

WorklogInput worklogInput = new WorklogInputBuilder(tarea.getSelf())
.setStartDate(new DateTime())
.setComment("Comment for my worklog.")
.setMinutesSpent(1)
.build();

Issue issue = restClient.getIssueClient().getIssue("ISSUE", pm);

irc.addWorklog(issue.getWorklogUri(), worklogInput , pm);
```

Could anyone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Two things, make sure the URI is correct. web.web.com/jira seems like an incorrect jira url.

Also if your server has a self signed certificate make sure you import it into your keystore.

The 404 is almost for sure the URI you are using.

Comment: Hi. The URI is correct(http://xxx.yyy.com/jira). Exists and i can read the issues. The problem is when i try to add worklog. i get that 404 error. :S